# Fetch Username from database and display on index page

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

i have database table client_info(id,first_name,last_name,email,passowrd).I login in to my site using email and password. on the top right in header section of index/home page ..first_name should display of same user whose email is entered...i:e Welcom:Johen if first_name=john where email=current_email. ..what command should i user echo or CHTML or which model..since index.php have no model its only layout layout/main.php file .using yii framework...

Answer (score 0):

The Yii way to achive this would be to create your own WebUser class which extends from the Yii class CWebUser. When a user is logged in, you should store his username in there. After that, you could simply do

```
echo Yii::app()->user->username;
```

and so on. A tutorial on this subject can be found here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/60/

Answer (score 0):

The Yii way to achive this would be to create your own WebUser class which extends from the Yii class CWebUser. When a user is logged in, you should store his username in there. After that, you could simply do

```
echo Yii::app()->user->user;
```